# Remember user position mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 node of pages. From each node I can redirect to another one and have breadcrumbs in every node(page).

I am redirecting from

> page1 --> page2 with this parameters in url: `ID=1,Name=3, Status=5` , and
>
> page2 --> page3 only `ID=1, Name=3`. If I am at 3rd level(page3).

When I navigate page2, it must redirect with this parameters ID=1,Name=3, Status=5

How do I solve this problem, if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) to solve your issue. It keeps track of a site map of nodes that represent pages, so when the user navigates to a page, it will be able to lookup in the map where the user is and build breadcrumbs (or a SiteMapPath) to the home page.

Its unclear exactly how you have your URLs constructed (using route values or query string values), but either way will work with `MvcSiteMapProvider`.

Reference:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160425143429/http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position